# Python - FOR loop to remove list items by file extension

Tags: python, python-2.7

I must be missing something fundamental as it's been a while since I've used python. I have a simple function that I'd like to return a list of .jpg's from a directory, but it is returning other files as well.

```
import os

def myFunction(directory):
    pictures = os.listdir(directory)
    for i,v in enumerate(pictures):
        if v[-3:] != 'jpg':
            pictures.pop(i)
    return sorted(pictures)
```

There are .gif and .htm files in the same directory. The .gif file isn't returned with the list, but the .htm file is. If I run this loop in the interpreter, I can see the .gif file gets popped, and then if I run the loop a second time, the .htm file gets popped.

What am I missing? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not change the list while iterating over it. That will screw the indexing.

Use list comprehension:

```
>>> pictures = ['abc.jpg', 'abc.gif', 'abc.png', 'cde.jpg']
>>> [pic for pic in pictures if pic.endswith('jpg')]
['abc.jpg', 'cde.jpg']
```

Or `filter()` with `lambda()`:

```
>>> filter(lambda pic: pic.endswith('jpg'), pictures)
['abc.jpg', 'cde.jpg']
```